# Listing city taxonomy as woocommerce chekout shipping city dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I have managed to add custom checkout city dropdown field by following method

```
$fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = array(
    'label'       => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => true,
    'clear'       => true,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'class'       => array('own-css-name'),
    'options'     => array(
        'New_York_City' => __('New York City', 'woocommerce' ),
        'Chicago' => __('Chicago', 'woocommerce' ),
        'Dallas' => __('Dallas', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
```

I want to get the option values from city taxonomy so I have tried the following method but it doesn't seems to work (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dasIm.jpg)

```
    $args = array( 
     'child_of' => 0,
     'type'     => 'product',
     'taxonomy' => 'city',
     'hide_empty' => 0
     ); 
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cityArray[] = "'".$category->slug."' => __('".$category->name."', 'woocommerce' )";
    }
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city2'] = array(
        'label'       => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => true,
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => array('own-css-name'),
        'options'     => array(implode( ', ', $cityArray ) )
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

Just replace the

- For Loop with

  foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $cityArray[$category->slug] =  $category->name;
      }
- Set option like this

  'options'     => array_values($cityArray)

Have tested the same and the results where as follows

[image]

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Its working but it generates the option value as 0,1,2 instead of category slug

What it generates
<select>
<option value="0">New york city</option>
<option value="1">Chicago</option>
<option value="2">Dallas</option>
</select>

What I need is
<select>
<option value="new_york_city">New york city</option>
<option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
<option value="dallas">Dallas</option>
</select>

Comment: just write the below statement 

var_dump($cityArray);

after foreach loop closing brackets and let me know the output on checkout page

Comment: If the var_dump statement results in the following output on check out page 

array (size=3)
  'New_York_City' => string 'New York City' (length=13)
  'Chicago' => string 'Chicago' (length=7)
  'Dallas' => string 'Dallas' (length=6)

Then in your case 
replace
'options' => array_values($cityArray)

with 'options' => $cityArray